# Change Accordion icon dynamically in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have made an expansion panel in Vue using Vuetify. I am using firestore to populate data in the panels and I have also given a button to "mark as complete" in the panels. My firestore query works just fine and the data gets updated. What I am not able to get done is change the background color or change the icon of the drop-down panels which is by default set to down arrow, after my database update as a form of graphical feedback to the user.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I need the expanded panel to either change its icon to a check mark or the entire background color to go green once I click on the right green check mark at the bottom of the panel.

I tried to set the color property of the panel headers dynamically but it doesn't work that way. Below is the code where I want it to work.

```
methods: {
    complete(id) {
      db.collection("orders")
        .doc(id)
        .update({
          status: "deliverd",
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("sdf");
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the `v-expansion-panel` [component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/) from Vuetify.

**Problem :** Dynamically change the icon or the background-color of `v-expansion-panel-header`

**Solution :** The component offers a prop called `expand-icon` which allows to change the icon of the `v-expansion-panel-header` - or via `action` slot

```html
<v-expansion-panel-header expand-icon="mdi-check" disable-icon-rotate>
  Item
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

```html
<v-expansion-panel-header :expand-icon="icon" disable-icon-rotate>
  Item
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

```html
<v-expansion-panel-header disable-icon-rotate>
  Item
  <template v-slot:actions>
    <v-icon color="teal">
      mdi-check
    </v-icon>
  </template>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

```html
<v-expansion-panel-header disable-icon-rotate>
  Item
  <template v-slot:actions>
    <v-icon color="teal">
      {{ icon }}
    </v-icon>
  </template>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

Please note the use of `disable-rotate-icon` to disable icon rotation when the expansion panel opens.

---

If you're not sure how this should be applied using Vue I suggest reading a quick [Getting Started](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started) guide. However I drafted a quick example using the vuetify components in this [CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-r7n2h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Please see this example just as a pointer, there would be 100 of ways how to implement this in an app. Like this, it's not meant to use in production code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I was fiddling around with the code and thought I'd just update the icon thru a field in the firestore document, that way it can be a permanent change and will persist thruout. I can update the icons in firestore without any problem, but re-rendering the icons in real-time is an issue. Do you know how to get around this? This is my update code :

`methods: {`
`complete(id) {`
`db.collection("orders")`
`.doc(id)`
 `.update({`
        `icon: "mdi-phone",`
       `})`
        `.then(() => {});`
`},`

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look at the codesandbox example